# How to display sub-report on the top of the group?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I have created a sub-report and I have empty place in the right side of my custom_group in my master report. I want my sub-report be in this position (in the right side of custom_group in the master report).

Does any one know how to do it in *iReport*?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking to move the subreport? Click the subreport in your master report. In the Properties menu, set the Left position.

If you're looking to do more than just move it, post your JRXML file so we can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the subreport and set the margin for it to 0. For that open your sub-report in iReport, in the *Report Inspector* right click on the report and click *Remove Report Margins*. Then save your sub-report and re-run the parent report (hit the *compile report* icon on top of the *Report Designer* to enforce the re-compile of all report resources): the sub-report's margin will be gone, there won't be any whitespace on the left side.